# Libgdx Stage.setActionsRequestRendering(true) not working as expected

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to disable continues frame rendering in LibGDX.

As stated in libgdx documentation [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering), it can be done by calling `setContinuousRendering(false)` and which worked well.

Other thing i want to do is when action is applied on some actor , every frame must be rendered until action has not finished. 
for that i called the method from stage `setActionsRequestRendering(true)` which changes nothing. frames are dropped and not rendered. 
Applied actions on the actors are working but it is applied directly without any effects.

What I'm missing here?

**Update :**

I have an Actor which is image and applying action to the actor like this.

```
img.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x, y, 0.5f, Interpolation.swingIn));
```

This actions skips first few frames. also fps logger displays random number of frames between 1-20 when action is active. There is no other issue which may affect frame rates.

Also this same action works as expected if this action is applied after dragging actor. but does not work if applied after clicking.

Action applied after drag.

```
img.addAction(Actions.sequence(
        Actions.moveTo(x, y, 0.5f , Interpolation.exp5Out),
        Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dragged = true;
            }
        })));
```

Answer (score 0):

At first [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering) is the wiki entry for continous rendering.

To anwser your question: You are missing to call

```
Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

on your own. Many default actions as mentioned in the wiki entry are calling this method, so they request a render call. For your own custom actions you have to do this manualy.

Comment: i read the wiki you linked here. Default Actions should call `setActionsRequestRendering(true)` automatically, if i understood it correctly. but my game does not draws frames. and that is the problem

Comment: @Prashant Do you override the default Action class? Then you use a custom implementation an you have to request rendering on your own. I mentioned that in my answer :)

It only calls automatically if you use some of the default Actions provided by libGDX, not the "default" one where you have to implement a "run"-method on your own. Default Actions provided by libGDX are for example  "MoveToAction"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm using `MoveToAction`. and not overriding `Action`. I will post part of that code here. may be you can help me check what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, that cleared a lot :D Yeah, do that ;) I will help you as much as i can.

Comment: am i doing anything ?